# Rails 3.1.1 in production - no such file to load 'ftools'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I run rails in production I get an error about ftools being missing.  I know newer versions of ruby use fileutils instead, but I'm not sure where ftools is being required from.

Any help?

```
0   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  306     in `rescue in depend_on'
1   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  301     in `depend_on'
2   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  214     in `require_dependency'
3   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb  417     in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
4   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb  416     in `each'
5   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb  416     in `block in eager_load!'
6   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb  414     in `each'
7   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb  414     in `eager_load!'
8   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb    51  in `block in '
9   /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb   30  in `instance_exec'
10  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb   30  in `run'
11  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb   55  in `block in run_initializers'
12  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb   54  in `each'
13  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb   54  in `run_initializers'
14  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb     96  in `initialize!'
15  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb    30  in `method_missing'
16  /webapps/my_app5/config/environment.rb  5   in `'
17  config.ru   3   in `require'
18  config.ru   3   in `block in '
19  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `instance_eval'
20  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `initialize'
21  config.ru   1   in `new'
22  config.ru   1   in `'
23  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   222     in `eval'
24  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   222     in `load_rack_app'
25  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   156     in `block in initialize_server'
26  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb  572     in `report_app_init_status'
27  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   153     in `initialize_server'
28  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    204     in `start_synchronously'
29  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    180     in `start'
30  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   128     in `start'
31  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  253     in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
32  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb     132     in `lookup_or_add'
33  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  246     in `block in spawn_rack_application'
34  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb     82  in `block in synchronize'
35  < td=""> <> prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
36  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb     79  in `synchronize'
37  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  244     in `spawn_rack_application'
38  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  137     in `spawn_application'
39  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  275     in `handle_spawn_application'
40  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    357     in `server_main_loop'
41  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    206     in `start_synchronously'
42  /home/my_app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@192/gems/passenger-3.0.9/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server   99  in `'
```

Comment: looks like some gem / plugin is requiring ftools in an initializer

Comment: make this the answer and I'll mark it as such.  I had a ftools in a controller I haven't used in over a year and it crept back in to my production app some how.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

use

> require "fileutils"

instead because ftools is not supported with ruby-1.9.x